# Mongoose findOne went to catch, fixed after deleting and rewritting catch

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jwt

I was trying to login with mongoose, but it always went to catch even after restart. But after i delete and rewrite the catch it's all good now. What's up with that?

Here is the code:

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username})
    .then(user => {
      const passwordCheck = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)
      if (passwordCheck) {
        const tokenUser = jwt.sign({
          id: user._id,
          username: user.username,
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
      res.status(201).json({token: tokenUser})
      }else {
        res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'wrong password'})
      }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'username is not found'})
    })
```

Comment: print err inside catch block and you will know what's the error

Comment: I tried that and it's empty

Comment: can you show how you print err

Comment: The issue was resolved by deleting and rewrite the catch, now i can't go back to my code's error state since it was the same as the resolved one

Comment: cheers go ahead for your next tasks...

Comment: just wodering why it happend lol